# 1064 Error on replication slave in case statement query

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

I have mysql replication setup where the LOAD SQL runs without any error on master but on slave it fails with error 1064 and replication breaks

So 1064 is reserved word issue but in my case i don't have any reserved words to put "`"(back tick) here.
The issue is the case statement in SET command.
i want the case statement SET and i cant put "`" on "case" or "then" reserved words.
Also if i copy this SQL on slave as it is and run then works without complaint.

Is there way to rewrite this query so that slave server wont have any issue with the case statement.

Master Server : 5.5.28-29.1-log Percona Server
Slave Server : 5.6.20-68.0 Percona Server

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES (
@Timeframe,
@reportdate
)
SET Timeframe = (
CASE
WHEN @timeframe LIKE '%(start time before request time)%' THEN
  'Immediate Requests'
WHEN @timeframe LIKE '%(start time less than 30 minutes after request time)%' THEN
  'Scheduled Requests'
WHEN @timeframe LIKE '%Start time more than 30 minutes after request time%' THEN
  'Delayed Scheduled Requests'
END
),
reportdate = date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Slave Error
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `reportdate`=date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day)' at line 3' on query. Default database: